# Access array values outside of function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to access variables outside of my function that assigns values to them. I thought the best way would be to put them into an array but cannot seem to figure out how to access them elsewhere in my code. My function is as follows:

```
function getYouTubeMeta( $post_id ) {
    $video_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rfvi_video_id', true );
    $api_key = "*********************";
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=" . $video_id . "&key=" . $api_key;

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($json);
    $time_stamp = $json_data->items[0]->contentDetails->duration;

    function duration($time_stamp) {
        $di = new DateInterval($time_stamp);
        return $di->format('%i:%S');
    }
    $youtube_duration = duration($time_stamp);

    $like_count = $json_data->items[0]->statistics->likeCount;
    $dislike_count = $json_data->items[0]->statistics->dislikeCount;
    $view_count = $json_data->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
    $comment_count = $json_data->items[0]->statistics->commentCount;

    $youtube_meta = array('like_count', 'dislike_count', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'youtube_duration');
    $result = compact($youtube_meta);

    return $result;
}
```

If I use print_r($result); I get:

```
Array ( [like_count] => 2954 [dislike_count] => 37 [view_count] => 271763 [comment_count] => 385 [youtube_duration] => 3:16 )
```

I need to be able to echo out each key value independently in my code. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php echo 'returned_like_count_value' ?>
```

Comment: echo $return[like_count] ??

Comment: Assign the return value to a variable. So: `$output = getYouTubeMeta($post_id);`. Whatever is `return`'d from the function will be put inside the `$output` variable. Then you can access that return like any other array. `$output['like_count']`.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanKuhn. Exactly the answer I was looking for. I can now access all values.

Answer (score 0):

First assign the results of your function to a variable:

```
$result = getYouTubeMeta($post_id);
```

This would loop through your array and echo out the keys and their values.

```
<?php
foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
  echo "Key=" . $key . ", Value=" . $value . "<br>";
}
?>
```

If you just want a particular value you can use:

```
echo $result['like_count'];
```